# How did someone join my single player world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have a Minecraft PE single player world. When I was playing somehow someone joined my game. How could/can this happend?

Answer (score 6):

If you have the "Local server multiplayer" setting on, anyone in the same network as yours can access your world.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure someone joined, or did you meet your first villager?
If someone joins, it will say " has joined", and they're name displays above them. 
If it's some weirdo that just says "hmm" and stands in your way, then it's a villager.